# Angular data-ng-href wrong path

Tags: javascript, angular

Foremost, excuse my English if it's not perfect.

I have a view where I return the results of the search form.

Everything works except the results for `pictures` and `users`. I have the data, it's visible in the view, I have the username, picture id, etc. but the links doesn't work.

The links looks like `localhost:3000/search#` instead of `localhost:3000/pictures/{{picture.id}}`.

I'm a noob with Angular but I know that I have the data because I can show the `picture.id` or the `user.slug` in the *data-ng-bind*, so I don't know why it doesn't work in the link...

This is my code, _results.slim:

```
- if can?(:read, Picture)
  div data-ng-class="{'col-lg-12': search.set == 'pictures', 'col-lg-4': search.set.id == 'all'}"
    .panel.panel-default data-ng-show="pictures.length > 0"
      .panel-heading
        .panel-title Pictures
      .list-group
        a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-ng-repeat="picture in pictures" data-ng-bind="picture.title || 'Picture #' + picture.id" data-ng-href="/pictures/{{picture.id}}"

- if can?(:read, User)
  div data-ng-class="{'col-lg-12': search.set == 'users', 'col-lg-4': search.set.id == 'all'}"
    .panel.panel-default data-ng-show="users.length > 0"
      .panel-heading
        .panel-title Users
      .list-group
        a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-ng-repeat="user in users" data-ng-bind="user.username" data-ng-href="/{{user.slug}}"
```

Can you tell me if you see something wrong?

Comment: I think you  need to remove the href="#" so ng-href takes place

Comment: Thank you @Gonzalo, it's perfect without href="#". It's strange because I have this one in the other links and it works perfectly..

Comment: I added it as an answer if it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `href="#"` so it does not override your `data-ng-href="/pictures/{{picture.id}}"`

Links should work fine after that